# Parsing error: Unexpected token => En Firebase

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase

Estoy tratando de poder hacer deploy a un archivo index.js en Firebase pero me esta saliendo este error:

> 129:41  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

**Este es mi código**:

```
const callSendAPI = async (messageData) => {
const url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/messages?access_token=" + fb_page_token;
try{
    const response =  await axios.post(url, messageData)
    if (response.status === 200) {
        var recipientId = response.data.recipient_id;
        var messageId = response.data.message_id;
        if (messageId) {
          console.log(
            "Successfully sent message with id %s to recipient %s",
            messageId,
            recipientId
          );
        } else {
          console.log(
            "Successfully called Send API for recipient %s",
            recipientId
          );
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
catch(error){
    console.log(error.response.headers);
    }
}
```

Estoy trabajando en **Firebase**.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const apiai = require('apiai');
const uuid = require("uuid");
const axios = require('axios');
```

Y esto es mi **eslintrc.json**

```
 "parserOptions": {
// Required for certain syntax usages
"ecmaVersion": 6
},
```

Por favor quedo atento a su ayuda y muchas gracias.

Comment: Que version de nodejs estas utilizando?

Comment: Firebase usa la version 6.0.0